# Ideal helmet shape that uses chiton armored goggles

Tags: science-based, warfare, engineering, armors

A while back I learned that [chitons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiton) have [hundred's of small eyes that allows them to perceive the outside world without compromising the there armors integrity.](http://www.sci-news.com/biology/chitons-ceramic-eyes-03453.html#:%7E:text=Marine%20biologists%20have%20long%20known,capable%20of%20forming%20focused%20images.)  This has also lead to some speculation and [research](https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/science.aad1246), actually producing armored goggles that mimic chitons are a long way off.  But assuming that we have the capability to manufacture such goggles/visors, what would the ideal shape be for eye protection?

Would they be slanted on a 45 degree angle?  Would they wrap around they eyes like modern goggles?

Some assumptions:

- Armor has advanced far enough to justify implementing such technology.
- The vision the goggles give are good enough to be used for military applications.
- The artificial chiton eyes do not impact the armors integrity at all, or very little.

Comment: A science-based answer would require actual tests and measurements as well as a round or two of design.

Comment: @Dan not really. Have a read of the [tag wiki page](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tags/science-based/info).

Answer (score 3):

**No goggles.**

[image: chiton]

The chiton has decentralized eyes - many tiny eyes distributed in and among its scales.  The loss of one or several eyes will not impair vision.

So too your helmet.  There will not be goggles to look out of.  There will just be helmet over the face.  The helmet will be covered with tiny eyes.

The point (as I see it) of the chiton eye helmet is to protect the eyes better while still allowing vision.  The best protection for the eyes is to cover them with the same stuff protecting the rest of the head - goggles are a weak point.  The wearer will be looking at a screen inside the helmet showing a feed from the many eyes.  The tiny eyes will be all over the helmet.  I could imagine the wearer could opt for various views - 360, 180, 90 degrees in front depending on what was going on.